# How to disable sprite renderer and mesh renderer in unity 3D programmatically?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

In my game I have a empty gameobject that has a sprite and a textmesh as child I want to access the sprite and the text mesh and turn off the sprite renderer and mesh renderer of the sprite and the text mesh programmatically & then turn it on. How?

Comment: Before asking your next unity question, first check if the unity tutorials do not already cover this extensively. http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/enabling-disabling-components

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a reference to the `GameObject` that contains one of these components.

Example of how to find a GameObject in the scene.

```
var obj : GameObject = GameObject.Find("Name Of GameObject in Scene");
```

Example of how to disable the renderer.

```
obj.renderer.enabled = false;
```